# How to set a label at the top center

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set a label in the top center of the view, I've already tried this

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.center.x, 25, 92, 46)];
```

But its not actaully in the center as I want, here is how it looks like: [image: http://i49.tinypic.com/e17mty.png]

And I want the middle of the label, in the x center, and not the beginning of the label in the center.

Comment: set the position properly for label. It will be (self.myView.center.x - (92/2)). As your label width is 92.

Comment: What happens when you add a large text in label ? and What is myView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does exactly what you programmed. Unfortunately there is always some basic math involved in UI programming.

One possible solution: 
Initialize it with some frame of any position but with the right size. 
Then set the lable views' center property accordingly.

```
[label setCenter:CGPointMake(self.myView.center.x, 25)];
```

Or simply set the frame in a way, that it takes all the space from myView's left to right and just set the text alignment to NSTextAlignmentCenter.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, self.myView.frame.size.width, 46)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Or calculate the top left corner accordingly and set the frame upon initialization. Use the center position and substract half of the width. Or use the full with of myView, substract the with and then devide by 2.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.center.x-92/2, 25, 92, 46)];
```

or

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.myView.frame.width-92)/2, 25, 92, 46)];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make label's frame width equal to view's frame width and set the alignment of label to Center.

Hope this Helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this ,

```
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    lbl.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the proper x-position as `view.center.x - (labelwidth/2)`.  Also set the `textAlignment` to `center`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CGPointMake` set center of label like this.

```
lblAppTitle.center= CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, 25);
[lblAppTitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it's center rather than setting rect

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, 92, 46)];
label.center = self.myView.center;
//Also if your frame is bigger than text then you can set this also
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int x=(self.myView.frame.size.width-92)/2;
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 25, 92, 46)];
lbl.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 92, 46)];
label.center = CGPointMake(label.bounds.size.width / 2, 25);
```

or this:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.center.x - 46, 25, 92, 46)];
```